# Can I use Isolation Forest algorithm if I have a "ground truth" dataset that has no outliers for initial training to compare new data to?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am guessing this is not possible, but I basically want to find outliers or anomalies in a new dataset compared to the "ground truth" dataset. If I attempt to train a model using Isolation Forest you must set a contamination parameter when training, but I don't think I can change this contamination setting when running the tests. Does anyone have any other recommendations for solving this problem or if there is a solution I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a supervised approach if you have labeled data that you can use for training. If you just want to evaluate isolation forest with your ground truth dataset you have to come up with the contamination factor ahead of time in order to conduct a more honest evaluation.

Assuming that you're using `scikit-learn` you can also use the `score_samples` method to get a score per sample:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.score_samples